# DOM JavaScript research for all elements and put to one input

Tags: javascript

I have this simple JS code

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-order-item-sku");
console.log(x);
document.getElementsByName("dpd_package_content")[0].value = x[0].outerText;
```

```html
<div class="wc-order-item-sku">a</div>
<div class="wc-order-item-sku"><b/div>
<div class="wc-order-item-sku">c</div>
<div class="dpd_package_content"></div>
```

I take TEXT from "wc-order-item-sku", and put into "dpd_package_content" but now I have many "wc-order-item-sku" and need all put into this same "dpd_package_content" I do not know how to resarch for all "wc-order-item-sku" on page.

Can I please for some tips?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889103/3091398).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, and iterate through all the `wc-order-item-sku` divs.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-order-item-sku"); // array of wc-order-item-sku 
var s = ""; // empty string 
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  s = s + x[i].outerText + "<br>"; // adds a line break to string 
}
document.getElementsByClassName("dpd_package_content")[0].innerHTML = s;
```

```html
<div class="wc-order-item-sku">Prod 1</div>
<div class="wc-order-item-sku">Prod 2</div>
<div class="wc-order-item-sku">Prod 3</div>
<div class="dpd_package_content" style="color: red"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is a down vote for my answer.